# Log a mac address and check if its valid

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi im trying to make a script where if you run it the first time it logs your mac address then if you run it a second third etc time then it will just check if your mac address is the same and the one logged when you first ran it I couldn't really visualize how I was going to do it I did make some beginning code but it wasn't working how I wanted:

```
import time
import sys
import logging
from uuid import getnode as get_mac
import re

logging.basicConfig(filename='mac.txt', filemode='w', format='%(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
mac = get_mac()
logging.warning(mac)
print(mac)

logging.basicConfig(filename='log.txt', filemode='w', format='%(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
log = get_mac()
logging.warning(log)
print(log)
sys.exit()

if mac == log:
    print("True")

else:
    print("False")
```

That was my beginning code it logs your mac address in mac.txt and logs your mac address a second time in log.txt then it asks if mac and log are the same and if they are true if not false but I couldn't find a way to log it every time on mac but only log once on log I am trying to achieve if you change to a different computer it would display false because your mac address in mac isn't the same in log but I wasn't sure how to turn my code in to something like that but as I said my mac and log both log every time defeating the point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will check if mac.txt exists and if exists it will check whether the current mac address is equal to mac address when the script first ran. I hope this is what you wanted.

```
from uuid import getnode as get_mac
from os import path
mac = get_mac()
if path.exists('mac.txt'):
  with open('mac.txt','r') as filename:
    if str(mac) == filename.read():
        print(True)
    else:
        print(False)
else:
  with open('mac.txt', 'w') as filename:
    filename.write(f'{mac}')
```